# What are the tools for generating the Test report for iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, user-interface, testing

I am doing the Unit Testing And UI Testing for My App. Now I want to know the entire Test case report with Success and failure like ExtentReport Tool [1]: https://extentreports.com/

Comment: You can check xcpretty, it has some basic formatting https://github.com/xcpretty/xcpretty

Comment: Thank you @TiranUt. Is there any SDK for generating the test case report ? like https://extentreports.com/

Comment: haven't met such